# Hash checker addon for Chrome downloads

Tags: chrome

Is there a hash checker extension that can check my files after being downloaded?

I'm using a hash tab on my windows, but it's a Windows shell extension not a Chrome extension. I also found quite a few extensions for Firefox like "Download Status Bar" which does just that, but have been unlucky so far with Chrome.

It would be great to get suggestions based on your experience for what regards efficiency speed and ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

I have Found a good hash Checker after testing many :Toolsley Hash & Validate

https://www.toolsley.com/hash.html

Easy Drag And Drop interface, Fast , Support Large Files , md5 , SHA1 , SHA256 , CRC32

Comment: [Google chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toolsley-hash-validate/egecppgmelnhbkjfnlnlfhiemenoimch?hl=en)

Comment: @aman207 That should be the answer :)